# Find first empty input field

Tags: jquery

This simple selector finds the first empty text input field in my form but skips over password type inputs:

```
$('input:text[value=""]:first').focus();
```

Is there a neat way to say :text or :password in the above statement?

Comment: try `$('input[type=password][value=""]:first')`

Comment: Are you looking to test the whole form and then focus on the first empty input?

Comment: Absolutely Jay, thank you

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18730453/23082833

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('input:text[value=""]').add('input:password[value=""]').first().focus();
```

I don't think there is a better way. That's what I thought before taking a look at *@Hari Das* answer which has an issue but brings alternative solution to my mind:

```
$('input:text[value=""],input:password[value=""]').first().focus()
```

Choose the one which is more readable to you.

Comment: Ah yes, I was trying to get to your second version but left out the input after the comma. Why does this have an issue? Do you know?

Comment: Surprising a little bit. Should work as well but it's recommended to use `input:password` instead of `:password` for better performance.

Answer (score 4):

Here a little custom expression :

```
$.expr[':'].is = function(a,b,c){
    return $(a).is(c[3])
}
```

That allow you to use `is` in a selector. You can achieve what you want with that :

```
$('input[value=""]:is([type=text],[type=password]):first')
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqLXA/)**

Comment: Thank you Karl but I don't understand how the custom expression works :-(

Comment: The syntax inside the `:is()` is exactly the same as the jquery method [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) and return a set of elements.

Comment: Like the reverse of :not() ?

Comment: @cneeds Exactly. If you don't want to create the expression, you could use `'input[value=""]:not(:not([type=text],[type=password])):first'`, but let be honest, it is unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

By using comma you can insert multiple selector. It works like an OR operator.

```
$('input:text[value=""]:first,input:password[value=""]:first')
```

Comment: The problem with that is you will have 2 elements. The `:first` must be outside the selector.

Answer (score 1):

The *visible* is there to skip any hidden fields, such as select2 autogenerated inputs.

```
$('input:text[value=""]:visible:first',input:password[value=""]:first)
```

Comment: password type fileds could also be invisible I guess. Thus `$('input:text[value=""]:visible:first,input:password[value=""]:visible:first')`