# JQuery & Rails: Focus on next empty input after typing enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm new with JQuery and I want to refactor my code to **focus on next empty input after typing enter key**. I have the following .html:

```
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="search-product">
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" class="search-product">
  </td>
</tr>
```

And my .js.erb:

```
let next_input = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find('input:text');
while(next_input.val()) { next_input = next_input.closest('tr').next('tr').find('input:text'); }
next_input.focus();
```

It works like a charm! But I think there is too much logic and I was wondering if it can be refactored to a more simplistic way like:

```
$(this).next($("input(:empty)")).focus();
```

Comment: Maybe this sollution could been helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251559/find-first-empty-input-field

Comment: Maybe this sollution could be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251559/find-first-empty-input-field