# can't make scroll to the first error message field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

```
if(jQuery('.required_content').length){
  jQuery('.second_indiv_step_wrap').animate({scrollTop:jQuery('.required_content').first().offset().top - 96}, 'fast');
    }
```

[Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjuve/182/)

How you see I have a form and with js I am doign its validation, it is ok, my issue is connected with scrolling to the first error message every time when we will have empty input field. But seems code isn't working at all.

Comment: use focus() function of tag. like $("#xyz").focus();

Comment: can you show me some example please - @bharatpatel

Comment: jQuery("input[type=text]").each(function(){  if(jQuery(this).val() == ''){  jQuery(this).focus();return false; }  }); after validation try this. may it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730426/jquery-selecting-first-empty-text-input check this url.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/patelbharat001/Cjuve/187/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code in jsFiddle, You have used lot of in-line styles.

Also you don't have to write `if condition` for each field.

So I have Cleaned up the code.

And this works for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .second_indiv_step_wrap {
            margin: 20px;
        }
        .second_indiv_step_wrap > div {
            margin:20px 0 0 0;
        }
        label {
            display:block;
        }
        input {
            display:block;
            width:250px;
        }
        textarea {
            display:block;
            width:250px;
            resize:none;
            height:200px;
        }
        .next_second {
            margin-top:20px;
            padding: 10px 15px;
            cursor:pointer;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        .required-field {
            border: 1px solid rgb(11, 75, 132);
            min-height: 52px;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-align: center;
            color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
            background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        }
        .required_content, .error_x_white {
            display:none;
            color:rgb(244, 73, 68);
        }
        .show {
            display:block;
        }
        .error {
            border:0 none;
            background: rgb(244, 73, 68);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="second_indiv_step_wrap">

        <div class="surname">   
            <span class="required_content">Required</span>
            <div class="fieldWrap placeholder-hide">
                <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                <input type="text" name="Surname" id="surname" class="required-field">
            </div>  
            <span class="error_x_white">Please enter surname.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="firstname"> 
            <span class="required_content">Required</span>
            <div class="fieldWrap placeholder-hide">
                <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="firstname" class="required-field">
            </div>  
            <span class="error_x_white">Please enter first name.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="country_citizenship">   
            <span class="required_content">Required</span>
            <div class="fieldWrap placeholder-hide">
                <label for="autocomplete">Country</label>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete" id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input required-field">
            </div>  
            <span class="error_x_white">Please enter your country.</span>
        </div>

        <div class="residental_address">    
            <span class="required_content">Required</span>
            <div class="fieldWrap">
                <label for="pinrestextarea">Address</label>
                <textarea id="pinrestextarea" name="Principal residential address" class="required-field"></textarea>
            </div>  
            <span class="error_x_white">Please enter your address.</span>
        </div>

        <button class="next_second">Submit this form</button>

    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.next_second').on('click', function () {

            $('.required-field').each(function () {

                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    $(this).addClass('error');
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.required_content').addClass('show');
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.error_x_white').addClass('show');
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass('error');
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.required_content').removeClass('show');
                    $(this).parent().parent().find('.error_x_white').removeClass('show');
                }

            });

            setTimeout(function () {
                $('.second_indiv_step_wrap .error').first().focus();

                $('.error').unbind('keypress');
                $('.error').bind('keypress', function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('error');
                });
            }, 100);

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you code is very nice, and it really works but my issue is that my error messages are on input field @Vinod Murukesan

Comment: Sorry I am not able to understand, how you need it to work, I have created above code according to your jsFiddle code, if you can upload a image of your actual requirement and send me path, then I may be able to help.

Comment: Thanks, I modified a bit your code but it helped me @Vinod Murukesan